# Configure AWS CPU Utilisation metric for Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have a AWS ELB instance up and running. I have enabled the Classic Load Balancer with minimum number of instances as 1.

What I want to test/verify is if the load on the instance increases an additional instance should be created. To verify this I wanted to configure the Scaling triggers.

Can you guide me on how to configure the Scaling triggers for Metric CPUUtilization? What should be the Upper threshold or Lower threshold?

Comment: Keep above 80% on an average to create more servers, Keep below 50% to delete servers.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you *not* use the Classic Load Balancer. These days, you should use the **Application Load Balancer** or **Network Load Balancer**. (Anything with the name 'classic' basically means it is outdated, but still available for legacy use.)

There are **many ways to create scaling triggers**. The easiest method is to use [Target Tracking Scaling Policies for Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scaling-target-tracking.html). This allows you to provide a **target** (eg *"CPU Utilization of 75%"*) and Auto Scaling will handle the details.

However, I note that you tagged this question as using Elastic Beanstalk. I don't think it supports Target Tracking, so instead you can specify a "Scale-out" and "Scale-In" threshold.

As to what number you should put in... this **depends totally on your application and its typical usage patterns**. You can only determine the 'correct' setting by observing your normal traffic, or by creating a test system and simulating typical usage.

**CPU Utilization** *might* be a good metric to use for scaling, but this depends on what the application is doing. For example, if it is doing heavy calculations (eg video encoding), it is a good metric. However, there might be other indications of heavy usage, such as the amount of free memory or the number of users. You can only figure out which is the 'right' metric by observing what your system does when it is under load.